# Perform commands on selected items in Midnight Commander

Tags: files, mc

How can I perform a command on the selected items ?

for example calling vim, or gimp for the 5 text or image files selected.

I tried to make use of the inlined command line at the bottom, but it doesn't take my selection into account

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Press `F2` for user menu and then choose `Do something on tagged files` or press `@`. In popup window you can provide your command.

It is important to notice that for each file command will be executed separately. It will be something like:

```
for file in files:
   COMMAND file
```

not

```
COMMAND file1 file2
```

Comment: this also works when the cursor is on a file but it is not *selected*

Comment: the selected item is automatically appended to the command.

Answer (score 16):

For one-liners, use `%t` at the command line, which gets substituted for a list of your selected items.

```
for F in %t; do echo "${F} is selected"; done
```

```
cp %t /var/somewhereelse/
```

Comment: Use `%f` macros as a substitute of current selected file name. Example: `vim %f`.